# Binary to string, space every 8 digit

Tags: php, linux, shell

How can I convert this string to have a space every 8th digit using PHP or Shell. From this:

```
0100010101110010011100100110111101110010
```

To this:

```
01000101 01110010 01110010 01101111 01110010
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The far fastest and also clearest method to solve that is most likely the following:

```
<?php
 $input = "0100010101110010011100100110111101110010";

 $newString = chunk_split($input, 8, ' ');
 echo $newString;

?>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
$str = "0100010101110010011100100110111101110010";
$str = implode(' ',str_split($str,8));    
echo $str; //output: 01000101 01110010 01110010 01101111 01110010

$str = str_replace(' ','',$str); 
echo $str; //output: 0100010101110010011100100110111101110010
?>
```

Comment: but I need do this vice versa

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 0100010101110010011100100110111101110010 | sed 's/......../& /g'
```

Comment: @drrcknlsn - `{n}` wasn't part of the sed language when I learned it, and I've never had occasion to relearn it. Regardless, your choice is better, assuming it is available to the OP.

Comment: `.{8}` works if you enable extended regex (`-r` on linux, `-E` on BSD).

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this from bash:

```
echo "0100010101110010011100100110111101110010" | sed -E "s/([0-9]{8})/\1 /g"
```

The -E for extended regex might be something else on Linux (GNU sed).

Comment: In GNU sed it's `-r` (though `-E` seems to work with GNU sed on Debian).

Comment: @Rocket : i constantly switch between BSD (OS X actually) and Linux, so it's a blur sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget `awk`:

`awk '{gsub(/.{8}/,"& ",$0); print}'`

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] echo "0100010101110010011100100110111101110010" | 
awk '{gsub(/.{8}/,"& ",$0); print}'
01000101 01110010 01110010 01101111 01110010
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "0100010101110010011100100110111101110010";
$newString = trim(implode('',array_map(function($value) { return $value.' '; }, str_split($string,8))));
```

Comment: This seems a little over-complicated.

Comment: It isn't as neat and efficient as chunk_split(), but demonstrates that even in PHP there's more than one way to perform any task